# Custom HTML5 Audio Controls won't work

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to make custom HTML5 audio event buttons. I know I can use the controls but I want to make my own my code is below:

```
<audio autoplay="true" loop src="vid/birth.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('audio').play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementByTagName('audio').pause()">Pause</button>
```

When I load the page the audio starts but the controls won't work, I click them and nothing happens. What am I doing incorrectly?

**Update:**

I was able to figure out that had some z-index atribute issues that was pushing the buttons to the background and making them unusable. After some CSS trickery I was able to get it to work using the code below:

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay="true" loop="1" src="vid/birth.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="audio.play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="audio.pause()">Pause</button>
```

Comment: ...getElementsByTagName("audio")[0].play(); you need another "s" in the 2nd one too

Comment: Well shouldn't those commends look for an audio tag regardless of what the ID is? Also I tried that and it did not solve the issue @dandavis

Comment: of course, if you did give the tag an id of audio, you can skip the dom crap altogether and just say <button onclick="audio.pause()">. some folks resent the auto globals, but i find them semantic and clean...

Comment: @dandavis That still did not solve the issue, even changing the ID did not do it.

Comment: it should work, there's not much to go wrong, show me what you tried and i'll take another look

Comment: @dandavis I did that as well and even though I'm skipping the DOM it still is not functioning. DOes it look like I'm missing something. I've look through all the API docs and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Well I tried this: `<audio id="audio" autoplay="true" loop src="vid/birth.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="audio.play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="audio.pause()">Pause</button>` That did not work then I tried changing the ID to audio and just having the DOM find that Id tag that also did not work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fq1682ub/ works, and so does http://jsfiddle.net/fq1682ub/1/

Comment: I actually figured it out I am using the z-index element to help with a background video that goes along with the audio file and it looks like when I push the z-index forward it makes the buttons clickable and it was functioning properly. Thanks a lot for your help @dandavis

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I was able to figure out that had some z-index atribute issues that was pushing the buttons to the background and making them unusable. After some CSS trickery I was able to get it to work using the code below:

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay="true" loop="1" src="vid/birth.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="audio.play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="audio.pause()">Pause</button>
```